# How do you go from high level to low level use case diagram?

Tags: uml, use-case

I need to create use case diagrams for a small game.  I have created what I think is a correct, high-level use case diagram.  I now want to create sub-diagrams.  Take "Play Game" for example, there are many actions involved in playing the game, like moving or jumping, so would "Play Game" become the system (box) in the sub-diagram?  I am not quite sure the proper way to expand use cases is.

[image: High Level Diagram]

Answer (score 2):

You would describe the scenarios behind the UCs starting with the sunny day scenario. This can either be described textual in the Cockburn way or by using activity diagrams using appropriately connected actions. If your modeling tool support this (hopefully) you would place those activities inside the UCs. Following would be to create collaborations and a class design in parallel.

I'd recommend to look into ICONIX since they have a quite neat design process model which did put me on rails many years ago.

Re. your question title: you do not create a "low level UC" since that's not the intention. UCs are about added value and that can not be sub-divided. Here I'd recommend Bittner/Spence as an excellent read.